# form javascript submit event

Tags: javascript, events, form-submit

I want to manage a form only with javascript, but the eventlistener doesn't worked for me. What's wrong?

My form:

```
<script src="init.js"></script>
<div id="search_box">
    <form id="search_form">
        <input type="search" name="search" autofocus placeholder="Google search" id="searchbox">
        <input type="button" value=&#9679; id="searchsign">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="search.js"></script>
```

In init.js file:

```
"use strict";

function $(selector){
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}

function $$(selector){
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

in search.js file:

```
$('#searchsign').addEventListener('click', search);
$('#search_form').addEventListener('submit', search);

function search(){
    console.info('search function OK');
    var searchvalue = $("#searchbox").value;
    var google = "https://www.google.hu/search?site=&source=hp&q=";
    window.location = google + searchvalue;
}
```

Comment: console errors?

Comment: search() is defined after assigning the event listeners.

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann: No, `search.js` is at the bottom.

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann it is hoisted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form's `submit` event will go to the form's action (no action = the current URL) and reload the page.

If you're handling it with JavaScript, accept the event argument and call `preventDefault` on it to prevent the default behavior:

```
function search(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
```

I would also suggest either not making your functions globals, or giving `search` a different name to avoid conflicts in the global namespace.

---

Side note: You need to URI-encode query string arguments, so change your `location` assignment to use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
window.location = google + encodeURIComponent(searchvalue);
```

---

[**Working copy on JSBin**](https://jsbin.com/hizemas/edit?html,js) *(Since Stack Snippets work in frames that don't allow us to move off to Google)*

Source of working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="search_box">
  <form id="search_form">
    <input type="search" name="search" autofocus placeholder="Google search" id="searchbox">
    <input type="button" value=&#9679; id="searchsign">
  </form>
</div>
<script>
"use strict";
(function() { // Scoping function to avoid globals
  function $(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
  }

  function $$(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }

  $('#searchsign').addEventListener('click', search);
  $('#search_form').addEventListener('submit', search);

  function search(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.info('search function OK');
    var searchvalue = $("#searchbox").value;
    var google = "https://www.google.hu/search?site=&source=hp&q=";
    window.location = google + encodeURIComponent(searchvalue);
  }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Code looks fine to me here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozbrvN)

The results aren't going to show because google does not allow itself to be iframed, but you can see your console logs are printing just fine.

If you are not seeing the same results as above in your code, then I'm guessing there is an issue with the order or manner in which you are including your files.

```
.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger `submit` event, do not add click event listener to submit button, instead change its `type` to `submit`.

Do not forget to add `e.preventDefault()` in submit function to prevent default submit behaviour and page reloading

```js
"use strict";

function $(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

function $$(selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

$('#search_form').addEventListener('submit', search);

function search(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.info('search function OK');
  var searchvalue = $("#searchbox").value;
  var google = "https://www.google.hu/search?site=&source=hp&q=";
    window.location = google + searchvalue;
}
```

```html
<script src="init.js"></script>
<div id="search_box">
  <form id="search_form">
    <input type="search" name="search" autofocus placeholder="Google search" id="searchbox">
    <input type="submit" value=&#9679; id="searchsign">
  </form>
</div>
<script src="search.js"></script>
```